# PHP installed but not working on a custom server

Tags: php, nginx, fedora

I have a VPS running Fedora, and I have installed nginx and PHP5.3.6.
Here is the phpinfo() file: http://199.167.198.149/info.php

However when I try to run another script (say, even "echo 'Hi!';"), it doesn't work and sometimes I get the error 'No input file specified.'

I'm quite new to the configurations necessary to run that sort of server; html files work fine though.

Do you have some tests I can run or a fix?

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that if you replace phpinfo(); by echo 'test'; in your info.php it doesn't work?

Comment: http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample#Common_Errors

Comment: Does your echo hi script end in .php?

Comment: 1-yes
2-Checking it out as well as the answer I got
3-yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have `SCRIPT_FILENAME` specified using [fastcgi_param](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFcgiModule) in your nginx config for the site.

Example:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass   localhost:9000;
  fastcgi_index  index.php;

  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my fastcgi path was not set properly!